# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture

Tags: c++, macos, g++, x86-64, sdl-2

First of all I want to say I realise this has been asked a dozen times, and I've read countless solutions without any luck so therefore I'm asking again.

I'm using OS X Mavericks 10.9.5, writing in Sublime 3 and compiling using terminal with g++

I'm trying to compile this simple file (test.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main () {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)) {
    std::cout << "I made it this far" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler line :

```
g++ test.cpp
```

This returns the error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
         _main in test-ebbae4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So, I've tried adding a lot of different flags, `-m32` only changes the result to throw `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:` and `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386`

I've tried different `-arch` variations, but I can't seem to get it to work. also played around with `-l -I` flags but I'm not sure I know what they do/how they could help..

Does anyone have a clue what to do next?

*EDIT* : Some additional information. I've tried using the .framework for SDL2, that didn't change anything, currently I'm using SDL2 installed through compilation of the source. Headers located in `usr/local/SDL2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> g++ test.cpp

You should specify the SDL library, too:

g++ test.cpp -lsdl2

You might need to include a path if its not well known to the compiler driver:

g++ test.cpp -L/path/to/the/library -lsdl2

---

Comment: I'm guessing /path/to/the/lib is usr/local/lib/ since this folder contains a bunch of files commonly named to some variation on libSDL2.a/dylib. Or am I mistaken? However, when I run `g++ test.cpp -L /usr/local/lib/ -lsdl` I get `ld: library not found for -lsdl` So I guess I've made a mistake again.

I do realise this is deep water for someone just getting into C++, but this was really the first error that I ran into, and now I've invested surely 8 hours on it, so it would be nice get it.. -

Comment: A couple of hours of sleep did it. I just had to change it to -lsdl2. This has been educational to say the least. I'll add an edit to your answer and mark it as the correct one. Thank you!